# Clang only: A pair<path, path> can be emplaced into a vector; so can a pair<unique_ptr, unique_ptr>; but NOT pair<path, unique_ptr>: Why?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, compiler-errors, clang

I have the following three snippets of code to demonstrate an easily reproducible issue.

```
using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    path dummy_path;

    // Snippet 1
    // Two paths
    // Succeeds
    //
    // vector<pair<path, path>> myvec;
    // myvec.emplace_back(dummy_path, dummy_path);

    // Snippet 2
    // Two unique_ptr's
    // Succeeds
    //
    // vector<pair<unique_ptr<int>, unique_ptr<int>>> myvec;
    // myvec.emplace_back(unique_ptr<int>(new int(13)), unique_ptr<int>(new int(12)));

    // Snippet 3
    // A path and a unique_ptr.
    //
    // **FAILS** on Clang, succeeds in Visual Studio
    //
    vector<pair<path, unique_ptr<int>>> myvec;
    myvec.emplace_back(dummy_path, unique_ptr<int>(new int(12)));

}
```

Here is the compiler error on Clang:

`error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> >'` (in reference to the second member of the pair, the `unique_ptr`, obviously).

It seems that for some reason, the failing case indicated is causing the copy constructor of the pair, rather than the move constructor, to be called.

This is Clang 5.0.2 on OS X 10.8.5.  (And VS 11.0.60610.01 Update 3 on Windows 7 64-bit.)

In my actual application, the data types are more complex but the error boils down to the one described in this question.

My question is twofold: **Why does the case indicated fail on Clang** even though the other two cases, which cover both data types, succeed?

Perhaps more importantly, however: **What can I do to work around this problem?**  Because my actual application is more complex, I do not have the option of not performing the emplace (or something equivalent) of the given pair into the vector - but if there's any other way I can get past this Clang issue to get that pair into that vector, I would be very happy.

Comment: Does `myvec.emplace_back(std::move(dummy_path), unique_ptr<int>(new int(12)));` work?

Comment: @jrok - I tried that (and would have included in the question, but wanted to keep the question as simple as possible).  The answer: No.  Adding `std::move()` around the `path`, the `unique_ptr`, or both, all still fails.

Comment: Clang version from [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e9f8c7e26df3674) compiles fine.

Comment: @jrok - That is hopeful.  Maybe it's a compiler flag.  I will start to dig.

Comment: @jrok With the following compiler flags in place, the problem appears: `-x c++ -arch x86_64 -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++`.  See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b90bf49e93c6535

Comment: The problem is the `-stdlib=libc++` compiler flag.  I am now trying to determine how to get rid of it from within the Xcode project settings for the compiler...

Comment: ... When I change the compiler settings to remove `-stdlib=libc++`, the compiler error is now `no member named 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std'`... What to do?  How come the compiler results are different in Xcode, even with the same (relevant) compiler flags, than in the coliru link?

Comment: On Mac you don't have any C++11 STL alternative other than `libc++` - removing this flag cause the compiler to lose the STL completely.

Comment: That is unfortunate... Therefore, do you think that in Xcode, there will currently be no way to build the sample code successfully?

Comment: No flags can help - see proposed solution in my answer.

Comment: @abyss: Note, that Xcode provides the option of either `libc++` or `libstdc++` in its `C++ Standard Library` setting option.  When I select `libstdc++`, however, the error I mentioned above - undefined `unique_ptr` - appears.  Apparently, although `libstdc++` is available in Xcode, the latter library is not yet compliant enough to provide `unique_ptr` in `namespace std`?

Comment: The `libstdc++` doesn't contain the C++11 stuff on Mac. It's here for compatibilty with the old gcc 4.2

Comment: ... and std::tuple<> has the same $&^* problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in libc++, sorry.  It has been fixed on tip-of-trunk.  I believe you can work around it by adding the following to your compile command:

```
-D_LIBCPP_TRIVIAL_PAIR_COPY_CTOR
```

Comment: Speaking of fast response - the issue fixed within 2 hours of being reported.  Congratulations, and thanks.

Comment: Here is the link to the bug report.  http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18249#c1 (for anyone interested).

Comment: My words were ambiguous.  It was already fixed on tip-of-trunk.  I hope my suggested workaround is working for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the preprocessor flag here does not seem to work.  After doing a full clean to remove any cached preprocessed files, and attempting to compile the file in question (with the following observed (relevant) command line: `clang++ -c -pipe -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -D_LIBCPP_TRIVIAL_PAIR_COPY_CTOR -g -gdwarf-2 -isysroot -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` (yes, two of the flags are duplicated)) - unfortunately, the same error is reported.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're only other option is to checkout the tip-of-trunk libc++ (http://libcxx.llvm.org), and put -nostdinc++ -I<path-to-libcxx>/include on the command line.  This will not require a rebuild of the dylib.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the libc++ Standard Library, since it has much less `pair` constructors within.

I.e. libstd++ has following constructor:

```
template<class _U2, class = typename
       enable_if<is_convertible<_U2, _T2>::value>::type>
constexpr pair(const _T1& __x, _U2&& __y)
: first(__x), second(std::forward<_U2>(__y)) { }
```

Which allows to compile your sample on Linux (with clang++). But libc++ has only:

```
pair(const pair&) = default;
pair(pair&&) = default;
constexpr pair();
pair(const T1& x, const T2& y);                          // constexpr in C++14
template <class U, class V> pair(U&& x, V&& y);          // constexpr in C++14
template <class U, class V> pair(const pair<U, V>& p);   // constexpr in C++14
template <class U, class V> pair(pair<U, V>&& p);        // constexpr in C++14
template <class... Args1, class... Args2>
    pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<Args1...> first_args,
         tuple<Args2...> second_args);
```

I guess, that the `pair(const T1& x, const T2& y);` is applied due to the first argument being non-rvalue reference.

---

The "hardcore" solution is to place this constructor by hand - inside the system library.
The `pair` is defined in `utility` file. If you want to be able to compile your code elsewhere, you may bundle the modified libc++ into your project - it's not a big deal, really.

Comment: Thanks.  The question is, what settings to set in Xcode to get the sample code to build?  No combination I have been trying for the past hour works.

Comment: Very much appreciated.  If you could mention the first step or two in the process of bundling a modified `libc++` into the project, I'd appreciate it.  I'm much more experienced on Windows.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I'm not familiar with XCode, but you can start from this page: http://libcxx.llvm.org/ the section "Get it and get involved!" - the library is built by one command. Then you just need to correctly setup compilation flags inside XCode project to hook with your library instead of the system one.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Actually, the shipping your own STL library and building with it - is a point for another question on SO :)

Comment: My apologies for un-accepting your answer (especially since YOU isolated this as a libc++ bug).  However, I did file a bug report with the libc++ project, and when Howard Hinnant of the libc++ project actually fixed the problem within two hours, I was torn about whose answer to accept.  I wish I could accept both, and I thank you for isolating this bug.  In the end, I felt that Howard's quick fix in the library itself warranted the accepted answer.  Again, thanks!

Comment: Note - from Howard Hissant's answer - no rebuild of the libc++ library is necessary; just including the proper header is required, since this problem occurs in a header file.